# not able to get php7 after add ppa:ondrej/php

Tags: ppa, php7

I added the repository by this command:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

WARNING: add-apt-repository is broken with non-UTF-8 locales, see
https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/56 for workaround:

```
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

More info: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmph7kev8sf/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmph7kev8sf/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key E5267A6C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmph7kev8sf/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key E5267A6C: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ondřej Surý" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

all seems good. then I run apt-cache

```
apt-cache search php7
```

which gives nothing.

this is my system information:

```
~# uname -a
Linux cspweb 3.13.0-123-generic #172-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 18:04:35 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I also try

```
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

the same result. any suggestion and hints is very appreciated.

Comment: please add the output of `sudo apt update`

Answer (score 4):

It seems ppa:ondrej/php is not support the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS according to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases
which indicates the standard support is ended April 2019.

After I upgrade my ubuntu to 16.04 LTS, I can install the php 7.3 from the repository.

Comment: You didn't mention you used Ubuntu 14.04 ?!

Comment: @Jim I had the same issue, there's probably quite a few of people using 14.04 because it's the default image on bitbucket pipelines https://hub.docker.com/r/atlassian/default-image/

Answer (score 0):

Once you've added a PPA you need to update APT cache before runing `apt-cache` or `apt install`.

```
sudo apt update
```

Comment: I forgot to mentioned I did apt-get update before run apt-cache.

Comment: update is not required since 18.04, add-apt-repository does it himself